# Iterating through mySQL MEMORY table

Tags: php, mysql, database-performance, temp-tables

I have a MySQL temporary table, created from a PHP file, and I need to iterate and reiterate through all of its rows in a double loop, therefore I am using `mysqli_fetch_row()` and `mysqli_data_seek()` a lot.

Performance is critical so I declared the temporary's table ENGINE to be MEMORY as I don't want  `mysqli_data_seek()` or `mysqli_fetch_row()` ever to touch hard disc. However, looking at my code I wonder whether the temporary table's ENGINE matters at all, since I simply drop the table immediately after I `SELECT * FROM` it and then it's up to PHP what will happen.

```
$q = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Drk ENGINE=MEMORY AS SELECT ...";
mysqli_query($q);
$DRK = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Drk");
mysqli_query('DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS Drk');

while (...)
{
  // some mysqli_fetch_row($DRK) and mysqli_data_seek($DRK, $i) calls here
  while (...)
  {
     // more of mysqli_fetch_row($DRK) and mysqli_data_seek($DRK, $j) calls here
  }
}
```

So my question is basic: what is actually happening behind the scene? Where is the result of `SELECT * FROM` stored and how to force it to stay in memory? Even better, I'd like to "directly" access and iterate through the rows of my temporary memory table, without ever calling that `SELECT * FROM Drk` that, superficially looking, seems redundant and copied everything once again.

Comment: Why don’t you just put the data you select from the actually existing table into an array – and then iterate over that however much you like?

Comment: Because I was lazy (also to answer your question on time). In addition, I assumed some magical properties of mysql. Ultimately I did what you said, thank you.